# InfoPath 2010 Form / SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: 2010, list, infopath, sharepoint-enterprise, form

I've been given an interesting project where I need to have a set of 3 forms as a readiness checklist for a software go-live event.

I have approximately 200 offices that need to fill out forms of checkboxes stating that this item is ready to cut over.  Each checkbox needs to have modified by, modified date, and a Home Office verification checkbox. I think the verification will need to use a workflow...

Each checkbox item will have a content type associated to it in correspondence to the different Form.

It appears that in order to get the amount of details that they require, I will need to create a column for each office, with each row being the varied list items they want to have verified.  I'm not certain how to do this in a SharePoint 2010 List.

Is there anyone out there that has experience with something like this?

I'm a newer SharePoint Administrator who has little to no development experience.  I'm hoping to work out a way to do this with InfoPath and SharePoint.

A little extra detail...

Each user logs in to our SharePoint site using their Active Directory credentials.  Each person could work in more than one Office.  We have special fields in the User Profile that keeps track of which offices they are associated with, and the one they were most recently logged in as.  We have a drop down list that they can change to switch their office.  I will have this list/form show their form based on this dropdown list choice.

I hope this information is helpful in giving me some much needed direction.

Thanks very much!