# Hide forms in SharePoint list where checkbox = checked

Tags: infopath, filter, form

Ok. So the problem I have is:
I have a SharePoint online form library which shows a list of warranty claims, the warranty claim form has a "Claim completed:" checkbox - and what I want to happen is that when checkbox = checked, that claim no longer shows up in the SharePoint online document list.

Pretty much just need to make them hidden so that they can still be searched for using the search function - just don't want 100+ claims showing when only 20+ are open and requiring attention.

What I've checked so far (other than good ol' Google Search and the http://office.microsoft.com/ site):
[How to hide particular SharePoint post use checkbox?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62974/how-to-hide-particular-sharepoint-post-use-checkbox) (nope);
[sharepoint list 2010 - forms](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87680/sharepoint-list-2010-forms) (nope);
[InfoPath 2010 Form / SharePoint 2010 List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27839/infopath-2010-form-sharepoint-2010-list) (nope);
[How to hide particular SharePoint post use checkbox?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62974/how-to-hide-particular-sharepoint-post-use-checkbox) (and nope);

If this question has been asked and answered previously, sorry for the repost - but I can't seem to find the <strike>droids</strike> answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a list view with a filter on the "claim completed" field.

- Create a new view or edit an existing view. Scroll down to the Filter section.
- In the dropdown "Show the items when column" select the "Claim completed" column.
- in the next dropdown select "is equal to"
- in the text box below type "no"

Save the view.

The view will now show only items where the check box column "Claim completed" is not ticked (i.e. where the value is "no" when shown in the view).

Edit: It sounds like you may have a list view web part on the home page. Edit the home page, then you can edit the web part and in the web part panel click to change the current view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer teylyn. I'll mark it as the answer, but one final question is how do I get this new view to transfer over to the main view on the homepage. I'll have a play and see what I can figure but any direction would be greatly appreciated.